# No variable data type in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have just started using JavaScript and it just seems strange to me that when the variable is declared,we don't have to specify the datatype. Is there any specific reason this is done?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really care about that stuff. `var a = "abc";a=5;` is valid code

Comment: JavaScript is **not** a strictly typed language (at least, yet).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is so **[dynamic types](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp)** can be used. Thus, this following code, whose [c](/questions/tagged/c) counterpart would be invalid, works:

```
var x;               // Now x is undefined
var x = 5;           // Now x is a Number
var x = "John";      // Now x is a String
```

Thus, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is not a strictly typed language.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is a loosely-typed language so variables types are determined at runtime instead of at compile time.

Comment: Variables don't have types. Only values do.